# Cuando muestro por consola req.files que recibo de una peticion de tipo post de HTML me muestra "undefined"

Tags: html5, nodejs, post, requests, express.js

estoy teniendo un inconveniente al utilizar req.files. Cuando lo quiero mostrar por consola el req.files que recibo de la peticion de tipo post del HTML me dice "undefined", pero si quiero mostrar por ejemplo el id de la imagen que recibo tambien por la peticion post del HTML si me lo muestra. Por lo tanto la ruta post esta bien hecha. No entiendo donde recide el problema.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] y a leer [ask]. Luego, te invito también a [edit] la pregunta y dejar el texto de tu código de ejemplo [y no imágenes del mismo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21). Un saludo.